# Types of onion address

Tags: bitcoin-core, network, full-node, tor, bitcoin.conf

I'm running a bitcoin core full node with Tor and I've configured a hidden service for that.
The point is: bitcoin core log shows me an onion address which is very smaller than the one I found in `/var/lib/tor/bitcoin-service/hostname`.
I noticed that other peers in the network connect with me using the small *.onion* address.
Which is the difference between these two types of onion address? Are they correlated eachother in some way?
I've also tried to use the longer *. onion* address in the *externalip* option inside *bitcoin.conf*, but it gave me an error.

Comment: The small address is the address onion v2 and the long address is the address onion v3, but I know a lot of tor, try to use the StackExchange tor https://tor.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I read somewhere that bitcoin core doesn't support onion V3. However, I'll repost this question in the tor forum